# Like % operator in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I am trying to run the code below but I am getting an error.

```
public MdFeedHandOff getFeedByHandOff(Integer handoff, Integer csiID){
        logger.error("*************getFeedByHandOff(): handoff value is "+handoff);
        String hql = "FROM MdFeedHandOff a WHERE a.handoff = :handoff  and  a.active  in ('A','I') and to_char(a.handoff) like :csiID%";
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put("handoff", handoff);
        List<MdFeedHandOff> batchJobList = searchForList(hql, param);
        return batchJobList.isEmpty()?null:batchJobList.get(0);
    }
```

I want to use like % operator in hql. Kindly help me.
I tried below line as well but its not working.

```
String hql = "FROM MdFeedHandOff a WHERE a.handoff = :handoff  and  a.active  in ('A','I') and to_char(a.handoff) like :csiID" + "%";
```

Comment: whats inside searchForList? how to you create query and set the params?

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public List searchForList(final String sentence, final Map<String, Object> parameters) {
  return (List) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
   public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
    Query query = session.createQuery(sentence);
    query.setProperties(parameters);
    return query.list();
   }
  });
 }

Answer (score 2):

You should just put the `:csid` parameter name in the query and add the % wildcard in the parameter you set. Also you do not seem to set the csid in the params map.

**Query**:

```
FROM MdFeedHandOff a WHERE a.handoff = :handoff 
     and  a.active  in ('A','I') and to_char(a.handoff) like :csiID";
```

**Params**:

```
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
param.put("handoff", handoff);
param.put("csiID", csiId.toString()+"%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like here:

```
String temp = "select p from Product as p where p.model like concat('%',:name,'%')";
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Product> query = session.createQuery(temp);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
```